# Remove piece of filename in .bat file

Tags: regex, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files in a folder using a .bat script.

Original filename: 
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T11UPA**_20200322T225116**_A03.nc

The bold part (second date/time) is what I'm trying to remove

Goal filename:
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T11UPA_A03.nc

I've tried this:

```
rename "S??_??????_???????????????_?????_????_??????_???????????????_???.nc" "S??_??????_???????????????_?????_????_??????_???.nc"
```

The different sections of the file should always have the same number of characters, and all files start with S and end in .nc

...but it doesn't seem to work properly. Sometimes files don't get renamed, and sometimes the get renamed, but incorrectly. Can anyone help? I've done many searches on stackexchange to try and figure this out, but none of the other solutions seem to work -- what regex do I need for this?

Here are some other examples of files to be renamed:
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVJ_20200322T231131_A03.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVK_20200322T231131_A01.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVK_20200322T231131_A02.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVK_20200322T231131_A03.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VWK_20200322T231131_A01.nc

should become:

S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVJ_A03.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVK_A01.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVK_A02.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVK_A03.nc
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VWK_A01.nc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution using [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```
@echo off
FOR %%F in (*.nc) do ( 
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nF") do ren "%%F" "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f_%%h.nc"
)
```

Screenie:
[image]

Comment: This looks like a more elegant solution, which allows for more flexibility in the naming convention (e.g. A001 or A01 suffix). Thank you - I will likely switch to this if my file names end up changing and I need to revisit the script.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used Alex's suggestion, but figured out how to put it in a .bat script:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /D %1

for %%F in (*.nc) do (
  set oldName=%%F
  set newName=!oldName:~0,44!!oldName:~60!
  rename !oldName! !newName!
)
```

Note: %1 is a path to the folder with files to be renamed (on the D: drive), provided as an argument to the .bat file in the command line.

What was important was to not have a space when defining variables! (e.g. oldName = %%F did not work but oldName=%%F did work)

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring syntax `%name:~start,length%`:

```
> set name=S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVJ_20200322T231131_A03.nc
> echo %name%
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVJ_20200322T231131_A03.nc
> echo %name:~0,44%%name:~60%
S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T184031_N0214_R070_T12VVJ_A03.nc
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! How does this work in a .bat script loop? I understand that if I use enabledelayedexpansion, I need to use ! instead of %. I tried both, but it still doesn't seem to be working. When I use echo to check what's happening, it returns either: "Output file is ~0,44%name:~60" OR  "Output file is ~0,44~60"